# extract colors from svg string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have `svg` file which is stored in string format in javascript. I want to extract all the colors mentioned in file and stored it in array.

color information would be denoted as `fill:#010101;` in file. I want to

1. search `:#` characted in file
2. Extract assosoate hex color
3. Store it in array
4. Again search for next color

SVG File could vary from size `1kb` to `450Kb`. I can use `.indexOf` to find first occurence of `:#` **but i am stuck in which method to use to get all colors in efficient way.**

Here is a fiddle of what i have done : http://jsfiddle.net/mumg81qq/1/ even fiddle gets hanged due to my svg string :(

Edit : How to modify [Javascript regex. Need to extract value from a SVG string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628961/javascript-regex-need-to-extract-value-from-a-svg-string) this answer to get hex/rgb colors from svg string ?

Comment: Will the SVG file change frequently, or is this more or less a static list?

Comment: @robbmj It will remain static

Comment: Could you not process the SVG file once and store the results in a JSON string. When the client needs the colours it could request the JSON from the server.

Comment: @robbmj : Do u mean color extraction process is handled by server side code ? and extract colors are requested by ajax  call ?

Comment: Yep that is what I mean. And if the list never changes you only need to process the file once. And even if it does change at least the AJAX call does not block the UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how efficient a regular expression would be at handling this, but something like this could work (however slow it may be) http://jsfiddle.net/vdugk40m/1/:

```
var info="fill:#010011;fill:#010012;fill:#010013;fill:#010014;";
var m, regex = /fill\:\#(\[A-F0-9]+)[;]/gi;
var colors = [];

do {
    m = regex.exec(info);
    if (m)
        colors.push(m[1]);
} while (m);

alert(colors);
```

If you need the # in the string, move the open parenthesis before the `\#`.

If you want to then reduce the array to only unique values (lifted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14438954/579148):

```
colors = colors.filter( onlyUnique );

function onlyUnique(value, index, self) { 
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}
```

Comment: @Shaggy I am looking at it now.. That's odd, in my simple example, it returns each of the values. But in the big one it is as you say.. repeating the same one.

Comment: Yeah that would be better

Comment: This regex can also deal with whitespaces and single quotes: /fill\s*[:=]\s*['"]\#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6})['"]/gi

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to capture hex values (i.e 6 characters following #) regexp groups comes in handy

```
var r = new RegExp('fill:#([a-zA-Z0-9]{6})','g')
var res= [];
while(result = r.exec(file)) { 
   res.push(result[1]); 
}
```

In the code piece above, I matched the 6 characters after #, and stored the captured group in an array called `res`

Here is a modified version of your fiddle to demonstrate

http://jsfiddle.net/mumg81qq/3/

Answer (score 2):

I like to keep it short, so here's my attempt:

```
var colors = [];
file.replace(/fill:(#[abcdef0-9]{6})/ig, function(v, c) { colors.push(c); return v; });
```

Will populate the array `colors` as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/ks92aau8/

Keep in mind that if you plan to support RGBA (alpha transparency) values, you'll need to use `{8}` instead of `{6}` in the regex.